# Fetch data from realtime database firebase in react native?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

I already have data in my realtime database. I can also fetch it successfully. Now what I need to do is output it in a tinder-like card view. I am currently outputting data using a 'Demo' file which exports a hard-coded array that contains sample information of some users. Using the demo array, the card output is working. But when I fetch data from firebase and store it in an array named items[], nothing is displayed on my output screen. My code is as follows:

**Home Screen**

```
 import React from 'react';
import { View, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import CardStack, { Card } from 'react-native-card-stack-swiper';
import City from '../components/City';
import Filters from '../components/Filters';
import CardItem from '../components/CardItem';
import styles from '../assets/styles';
import Demo from '../assets/demo';;
import {db} from '../config/config';



class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = ({
      items: []
    });
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    var items = [];
    db.ref('cards').once('value', (snap) => {
      
    snap.forEach((child) => {
      let item = child.val();
      item.id = child.key;
      items.push({
        pet_name: child.val().pet_name,
        pet_gender: child.val().pet_gender,
        pet_age: child.val().pet_age,
        pet_breed: child.val().pet_breed,
        photoUrl: child.val().photoUrl, 
      }); 
      
    });
    //console.log(items)   
   
    this.setState({ items: items });
    console.log(items);
  });

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ImageBackground
      source={require('../assets/images/bg.png')}
      style={styles.bg}
    >
      <View style={styles.containerHome}>
        <View style={styles.top}>
          <City />
          <Filters />
        </View>

        <CardStack
          loop={true}
          verticalSwipe={false}
          renderNoMoreCards={() => null}
          ref={swiper => {
            this.swiper = swiper
          }}
        >
          {Demo.map((item, index) => (
            <Card key={index}>
              <CardItem
                image={item.image}
                name={item.name}
                description={item.description}
                actions 
                onPressLeft={() => this.swiper.swipeLeft()}
                onPressRight={() => this.swiper.swipeRight()}
              />
            </Card>
          ))}
        </CardStack>
      </View> 
    </ImageBackground>
    )
  }
}

    export default Home;
```

**Demo Data**

```
module.exports = [
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'whatever',
        status: 'Online',
        match: '78',
        description:
            'Full-time Traveller. Globe Trotter. Occasional Photographer. Part time Singer/Dancer.',
        message:
            'I will go back to Gotham and I will fight men Iike this but I will not become an executioner.',
        image: require('./images/01.jpg')
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Clementine Bauch',
        match: '93',
        description:
            'Full-time Traveller. Globe Trotter. Occasional Photographer. Part time Singer/Dancer.',
        status: 'Offline',
        message: "Someone like you. Someone who'll rattle the cages.",
        image: require('./images/02.jpg')
    }

];
```

**fetching data:**

```
import {db} from '../config/config';

var items = [];
db.ref('cards').once('value', (snap) => {
      
    snap.forEach((child) => {
      let item = child.val();
      item.id = child.key;
      items.push({
        pet_name: child.val().pet_name,
        pet_gender: child.val().pet_gender,
        pet_age: child.val().pet_age,
        pet_breed: child.val().pet_breed,
        photoUrl: child.val().photoUrl, 
      }); 
      
    });
    //console.log(items)   
    for (var i in items){
      console.log(items[i]) 
    }   
  });

  export var items;
```

I want to use my items[] array instead of the Demo hard-coded array. How do I do this?
**The output of items[] array:**

```
Array [
  Object {
    "pet_age": "11",
    "pet_breed": "golden retriever",
    "pet_gender": "male",
    "pet_name": "dawn",
    "photoUrl": "picture",
  },
  Object {
    "pet_age": "7",
    "pet_breed": "German",
    "pet_gender": "Male",
    "pet_name": "Rambo",
    "photoUrl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/woofmatix-50f11.appspot.com/o/pFkdnwKltNVAhC6IQMeSapN0dOp2?alt=media&token=36087dae-f50d-4f1d-9bf6-572fdaac8481",
  },
]
```

**CardItem component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from '../assets/styles';

import { Text, View, Image, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Icon from './Icon';

const CardItem = ({
  actions,
  description,
  image,
  matches,
  name,
  pet_name,
  pet_gender,
  pet_age,
  onPressLeft,
  onPressRight,
  status,
  variant
}) => {
  // Custom styling
  const fullWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
  const imageStyle = [
    {
      borderRadius: 8,
      width: variant ? fullWidth / 2 - 30 : fullWidth - 80,
      height: variant ? 170 : 350,
      margin: variant ? 0 : 20
    }
  ];

  const nameStyle = [
    {
      paddingTop: variant ? 10 : 15,
      paddingBottom: variant ? 5 : 7,
      color: '#363636',
      fontSize: variant ? 15 : 30
    }
  ];

  return (
    <View style={styles.containerCardItem}>
      {/* IMAGE */}
      <Image source={image} style={imageStyle} />

      {/* MATCHES */}
      {matches && (
        <View style={styles.matchesCardItem}>
          <Text style={styles.matchesTextCardItem}>
            <Icon name="heart" /> {matches}% Match!
          </Text>
        </View>
      )}

      {/* NAME */}
      <Text style={nameStyle}>{name}</Text>

      {/* DESCRIPTION */}
      {description && (
        <Text style={styles.descriptionCardItem}>{description}</Text>
      )}

      {/* STATUS */}
      {status && (
        <View style={styles.status}>
          <View style={status === 'Online' ? styles.online : styles.offline} />
          <Text style={styles.statusText}>{pet_age}</Text>
        </View>
      )}

      {/* ACTIONS */}
      {actions && (
        <View style={styles.actionsCardItem}>
           <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.button, styles.red]} onPress={() => {
            this.swiper.swipeLeft();
          }}>
            <Image source={require('../assets/red.png')} resizeMode={'contain'} style={{ height: 62, width: 62 }} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.button, styles.orange]} onPress={() => {
            this.swiper.goBackFromLeft();
          }}>
            <Image source={require('../assets/back.png')} resizeMode={'contain'} style={{ height: 32, width: 32, borderRadius: 5 }} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.button, styles.green]} onPress={() => {
            this.swiper.swipeRight(); 
          }}> 
            <Image source={require('../assets/green.png')} resizeMode={'contain'} style={{ height: 62, width: 62 }} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default CardItem;
```

Comment: What happens when you `console.log(items)` after filling your items array for firebase? Is it empty or full? Also, why are you still mapping `Demo` in your code. Where do you map out the `items` array?

Comment: when i console.log(items) it shows me the data inside the items[] array. You can see it in the code above. Im supposed to map the items array instead of the Demo array but when i do that my cardItem component doesnt work and nothing gets displayed on my mobile screen.